# Google Maps button controls not showing

Tags: api, user-interface, controls, maps

I'm having an issue with the map controls not showing. What's the cause of this and will there be a fix soon? It looks like this is coming as part of an update to Googles controls / API. See image for an example of the issue

[Map issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zzqH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect Google maps like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&key...
```